# Is $ x^3 $ convex , on positive x-axis

Tags: functions

Intuitively its epigraph looks so convex to me. But when I tried to prove it is convex by proving

$ f(x) \ge f(y) +f'(y)(x-y) $ for $ x,y \ge 0$

I've got 
$ x^3 \ge y^3 +6xy -6 y^2 $ which is wrong when $x$ is 0 and $y$ is 10.

Is it indeed not convex and I mistakenly thought its epigraph is convex?

Comment: It is convex; try showing $f''(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Do you think $f'(y)=6y$? Isn't it  $f'(x)=3y^2$ ?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: But then I will get, $ 2y^3+x^3 \ge 3xy^2 $. Is it indeed true for all$ x, y, > 0 $ ?

Comment: You can check this inequality: $x^3+2y^3-3xy^2=(x-y)^2(x+2y)\ge 0$ for $x,y\ge0$.

Comment: It works!. Thank you so much! But can I ask if it is just a formula that popped up in your head or there is some trick/rule to factorize it. I have had no clue until you provided the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To start, the actual definition of convexity is as follows:
$$f\left(tx+(1-t)y\right)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$$

A better way, as suggested by Theo Bendit, is to prove $f''(x)\geq0$.

Comment: I started with the definition but could not prove it. Too many terms are there...

Answer (score 1):

If you'd really like to use the definition directly, try showing that
$$tx^3+uy^3-(tx+uy)^3=tu(x-y)^2(t(2x+y)+u(x+2y))$$
whenever $t+u=1$.